# in Jquery how to remove/hide the particular text from HTML DOM element

Tags: jquery

I am new to Jquery, please let me know how to hide the particular text from UI,I don't have any selectors to choose except the text, please help me

Here is Need to remove 'Customer designation' and 'Commericial' filed
Here is the Image which has dynamic generated DOM element.
Please help me , I need to remove/hide following two fields from  DOM

```
<span class="i-label">Customer Designation: </span>
<span class="i-value">Commercial </span>
```

I have tried below code, but it did not solve :  this.element.find('[span=Commercial]').hide();
$('[span=Commercial]').hide();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [contains](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/):

```js
$("span:contains('Commercial')").hide()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="i-label">Customer Designation: </span>
<span class="i-value">Commercial </span>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Christian Carrillo, it worked, Much appreciated for your help

Answer (score 0):

`$('.i-label').hide()` to hide and if you like to remove it, `$('.i-label').remove()`.
If you want to hide it but also want to hold the space (width,height) of the element, use

```
$('.i-label').css('visibility', 'hidden')
```

For the other element you can do it the same way, just change the selector to:

```
$('.i-value')
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, But I can't hide the ".i-label" as I have explained in teh Image , it is dynamic generated DOM, which has many i-label fields, so I need to hide only mine two items :     <span class="i-label">Customer Designation: </span>
<span class="i-value">Commercial </span>